# Getting data from Netlify CMS to Gatsby JS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm creating  a site using Netlify CMS + Gatsby. I already have the site structure and some data in Netlify, but I'm having some issues getting the data into Gatsby.  This is what I've got so far

```js
import React from 'react'

export default class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  render({data}) {
    const { edges: posts } = data.allMarkdownRemark

    return (
      <section className="section">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="content">
            <h1 className="has-text-weight-bold is-size-2"></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark(filter: {frontmatter: {templateKey: {regex: "/home-page|media-page/"}}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt(pruneLength: 400)
          id
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            templateKey
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

And I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: Do you still need help with this? You haven't accepted an answer so the question is still open.

Answer (score 2):

The `props` are not passed into the render as arguments.

**Try:**

```js
import React from 'react'

export default class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { edges: posts } = this.props.data.allMarkdownRemark

    return (
      <section className="section">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="content">
            <h1 className="has-text-weight-bold is-size-2"></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark(filter: {frontmatter: {templateKey: {regex: "/home-page|media-page/"}}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt(pruneLength: 400)
          id
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            templateKey
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is destructuring:

```
render({ data })
```

That's similar to doing this:

```
render(props) {
  data = props.data
}
```

The issue you're experiencing is that `render` doesn't receive any arguments/props.

The solution is to use `this.props`, as recommended by @talves' answer.